# Batch knowing its invoker: cmd.exe or powershell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I wonder how to check if a batch file is executed by `cmd.exe` or instead by `powershell`

I discovered that the ENV variable `%CmdCmdLine%`is set to something in `cmd.exe` and *should not* be set inside a powershell shell.

But if I run a batch file in powershell it temporary assumes a value like `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\path\to\check-interpreter.bat""`

Given also the inability of batch to check IF PATTERN I cannot find a way to let my batch file be able to know which command interpreter is running.

In the below code I tried to use `findstr /R` to check `cmd` at the start of the line. Infact inside `cmd.exe` the line should start with `cmd.exe ...` while in `powershell` should start with the full path `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c ...`

Here my attempt:

```
    @ECHO OFF
    FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`echo %CmdCmdLine% ^^^| findstr /R 
    "^cmd"`) DO (
    SET var=%%F
    )
    ECHO var set to: %var%
    REM IF [%var%]==[]  ECHO var set to: %var%
    IF DEFINED var (
            ECHO CmdCmdLine founnd!
            ECHO VAR        : %var%
            ECHO COMMANDLINE: %CmdCmdLine%
    ) ELSE (
            ECHO CmdCmdLine NOT found..
    )
```

The problem in the above code is that `var` is not populated at all:

```
# cmd.exe
C:\path\to>.\check-interpreter.bat
CmdCmdLine founnd!
COMMANDLINE: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"

# powershell
PS C:\path\to> .\check-interpreter.bat
CmdCmdLine founnd!
COMMANDLINE: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\path\to\check-
interpreter.bat""
```

Comment: Ultimately, a batch file will always be executed by CMD.EXE. It is the batch interpreter. What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Batch files are always executed by `cmd`, since PowerShell doesn't know how to handle them and just kicks off `cmd` to run them. Checking for a particular "form" of the command line is needlessly fragile -- nothing prevents anything from using the same form as PowerShell, nor is PowerShell required to use the same form from version to version. Why not have PowerShell supply an argument to the batch file to indicate it's being called from PowerShell?

Comment: @Christian.K the actual problem is that I'm trying to modify a batch file generally used double clicking it and that ends with `cmd /K` but this is not correct if you invoke it in a powershell command line window

Comment: When you doubleclick, a batch file, as many people do, using your terms, its invoker would be explorer.exe, but it would still be run by its registered executable, i.e. cmd.exe. Perhaps, depending upon clarification of the above comments, (via [Edit]), you could try to determine the parent process of the running cmd.exe process. _<Edit>The question is, for what reason does your batch file end with `cmd /K`? What exactly is the scripts' intention?_

Comment: @Compo the batch is intended to leave an open shell, for this reason it ends with `cmd /k`

Comment: Have you tried to find an alternative to that hack? That is not technically keeping the running cmd.exe open for use, it is keeping it open in the background, waiting until a new cmd.exe instance has completed, before itself immediately closing.

Comment: This means that the visible cmd.exe, is invoked by cmd.exe, which was run as the default application for the .bat extension from a powershell.exe process, which was in turn invoked via explorer.exe. Do you see now, how confusing it has all become?

Comment: You could know if PowerShell is running via `tasklist` and _assume_ in this case that the Batch file was started by PS. Of course, if there is _another instance_ of PS running, this method would not work...

Comment: To rely on tasklist is not suitable: you cannot assume other powershell instances running or not.  I wonder why `findstr` is failing so badly interceptind `^cmd` at the start of the string. The `^` should be the very beginning of the string, not generally in the first part of the string